# Problem with custom armor

Tags: modeling

Good evening, first of all I am completely new to this BLender so I am a little lost, and the issue is that I am trying to create an armor, but when I attached the part of the leather ropes to the Armature, although in principle it moves with the movement and it fits in principle where it is supposed to... When I try to import the GR2 again to see that everything is fine it always places it at the bottom... And in the game it looks like this on the ground. Someone who has experienced something similar could enlighten me... Thank you[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)